# Find Size / Length of text in SharePoint Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

How to find size / length / number of characters in a text based column through SharePoint Designer Workflow?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way: you can create a calculated column in your list and use the following formula to find the length of your column(Title):

```
=LEN([Title])
```

Then you use the calculated column in your workflow based on your requirement.

Comment: Why should one go through first creating new column then applying LEN func there... It is just one single action.. isn't there a way to apply it in SPD??